# ¿Cómo pasar valor de una tabla a un input en react?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una tabla en la cual hay un botón de edición, dicho botón abre un modal con un componente el cual tiene un formulario en el que quiero que aparezcan los valores de el registro a editar.

Tengo una tabla en react de la siguiente forma:

```
{
                (() => {
                    if (this.state.table == '' || this.state.table == null){
                        return (
                            <center>Datos no encontrados</center>
                        );
                    }else{
                        return (
                            <table className="striped">
                                <thead>
                                <tr className="titlesRow">
                                                    <th>Id</th>
                                                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                                                    <th>Fecha inicial de contrato</th>
                                                    <th>Fecha final de contrato</th>
                                                    <th>Opciones</th>
                                                </tr>    
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {
                                        this.state.table.map((item, index) => {
                                            return(
                                                <tr key={index + 1}>
                                                    <td>{item.idbooking_be_config}</td>
                                                    <td>{item.descripcion}</td>
                                                    <td>{item.vigencia_inicio}</td>
                                                    <td>{item.vigencia_final}</td>
                                                    <td><a data-target="modal2" className="btn-floating modal-trigger" href="#modal2" table={this.state.table}><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        );
                    };
                })
                ()
            }
```

En dicha tabla tengo un botón para hacer edición de el registro que hay en la tabla el cual abre un modal con un componente:

```
<div id="modal2" className="modal modal-fixed-footer">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <h5 className="title">Edit Configuracion</h5>
                        <EditConf id="Edit" descripcion={this.state.table}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#!" className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" ><i className="material-icons">close</i>Close</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

el formulario dentro de dicho componente esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<div className='col s12 m12 l12'>
                    <div className= 'row'>
                   <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
                           <input value={this.props.descripcion} onChange={this.onInputChangedesc.bind(this)} name="descripcion" type="text" className='validate'/>
                           <label htmlFor='descripcion'>Descripcion</label>
                       </div>
                       <div className='col s12 m4 l4'>
                           <label htmlFor='clienteint'>Cliente interno</label> 
                               <select name='clienteint' value={this.props.idfin_cliente_interno || ''} onChange={this.handlerUpdate.bind(this)} className='browser-default'>
                                   { this.state.getSearchIntclient.map((clienteint)=>
                                       <option key={clienteint.value} value={clienteint.value}>{clienteint.text}</option>)
                                   }
                               </select>
                       </div>
                       <div className="row-in">
                           <div className='input-field col s6'>
                               <input  value={this.props.id_cliente } onChange={this.handlerUpdate.bind(this)} name="cliente" type="number" className='validate'></input>
                               <span className="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Cliente</span>
                           </div>
                           <div className="row">
                               <ul >
                                   <li><a data-target="modal1" className="btn-floating modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i className="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
                               </ul>
                               <label htmlFor='cliente'>Busqueda</label>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>                        
                    <div >
                   <div className='col s12 m10 l10'>
                   <button onClick={this.handlerSubmit} type='submit' className="btn waves-effect waves-light" data-position="bottom" ><i className="material-icons right">save</i>SAVE</button>
               </div>
               </div>
           </div>  
       </div>
```

Quiero que en los inputs aparezca el valor del registro que se va a editar lo cual no se como hacerlo espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentaré ayudarte un poco en lo que tengas confusión. Lo primero que noto es la especificación de lo que son `props` y lo que es el `state`, entonces para explicarte brevemente. Los `props` son las propiedades que nos llegan directamente desde el componente padre que renderiza, te pondré un ejemplo:

```
const ComponenteConProps = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{props.nombre} {props.apellido || ''}</h1>
  </div>
);

const App = (props) => (
  <div>
    <ComponenteConProps nombre={'foo'} />
  </div>
);
```

Como ves, al momento de pasarle `<ComponenteConProps nombre={'foo'} />` le estamos diciendo al componente que tendrá un `prop` llamado `nombre`, por lo cual desde `ComponenteConProps` podremos acceder a `props.nombre` si quisiéramos que también mostrara el apellido, sería cuestión de hacerlo de esta forma: `<ComponenteConProps nombre={'foo'} apellido={'bar'} />`

Los `props` son externos al componente, es decir, `ComponenteConProps` no puede modificar esos `props`, a diferencia del `state` que si es interno del componente, y si se puede modificar, aquí hay una prueba de un componente con `state`:

```
class ComponenteConState extends React.Component {
  state = { nombre: 'foo', apellido: 'bar' }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>{ this.state.nombre } { this.state.apellido || '' }</h1>
    </div>
  }
}

const App = (props) => (
  <div>
    <ComponenteConState />
  </div>
);
```

Como ves en este segundo ejemplo, con el `state` definido, no necesitamos pasarle `props` al componente, si no que lo hacemos de una forma más limpia `<ComponenteConState />` porque internamente ese componente ya utiliza el `state`.

Habiendo explicado esto, entonces empiezo a ayudarte en tu problema. Lo primero que debes hacer es que en la tabla debes definir una función o método para que al momento que le den click al botón de editar, se pueda guardar en el estado (`state`) cual será el objeto a editar, entonces podemos definir algo así:

```
onClickEdit(e, item) {
  // set state es la función mágica de react que te permite cambiar valores de forma reactiva
  this.setState({ toEdit: item });
}
```

> **NOTA:** Ten en cuenta, que si quieres que te funcione, esta función debe estar dentro de una clase, y esa clase debe ser la que renderiza tu tabla

Definiendo esa función solo necesitamos ir a donde renderizas tu tabla y modificar esta línea en el `tbody` donde recorres tu tabla con un `map`:

```
...
<td><a onClick={(e) => this.onClickEdit(e, item)} data-target="modal2" className="btn-floating modal-trigger" href="#modal2" table={this.state.table}><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
...
```

Con eso funcionando, solo debes definir en tu componente `EditConf` cuales serán los `props` con los que va a funcionar. Para lo que yo te recomiendo empezar con definirlo así: `{ this.state.toEdit && <EditConf item={this.state.toEdit} /> }`. Y para que en tu componente `EditConf` pueda verse, entonces ya sabes que ese `item` que renderizas en tu tabla, llegará como `props` por lo que puede ser recuperado así: `this.props.item.description` por ejemplo, por lo que tu componente sería algo así:

```
<div className='col s12 m12 l12'>
  <div className= 'row'>
    <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
      <input value={this.props.item.descripcion} onChange={this.onInputChangedesc.bind(this)} name="descripcion" type="text" className='validate' />
      <label htmlFor='descripcion'>Descripcion</label>
    </div>
    <div className='col s12 m4 l4'>
      <label htmlFor='clienteint'>Cliente interno</label> 
      <select name='clienteint' value={this.props.item.idfin_cliente_interno || ''} onChange={this.handlerUpdate.bind(this)} className='browser-default'>
        { this.state.getSearchIntclient.map((clienteint)=>
          <option key={clienteint.value} value={clienteint.value}>{clienteint.text}</option>)
        }
      </select>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Fíjate que para acceder a una `key` del objeto que quiero editar dentro del componente, debe anteceder a: `this.props.item`. Si no quieres que se llame `item` si no tabla, entonces puedes pasarlo así: `{ this.state.toEdit && <EditConf tabla={this.state.toEdit} /> }` y dentro de `EditConf` sería anteceder a: `this.props.tabla`, o sea, para obtener la descripción sería: `this.props.tabla.descripcion`.

Espero haberte ayudado con tu pregunta, y que hayas podido resolver dudas, cualquier pregunta comenta

Comment: Gracias, aprecio mucho tu ayuda tan acertada. Problema resuelto

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco tenes que hacer una peticion ajax que te busque ese objeto , te obtenga los datos y luego los insertas en la modal segun el campo que querras poner.

```
 function detalleRegistro(fileID){
var nombre = fileID;
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax/detalle-archivo.php",//aqui pones la url de donde vas a enviar 
                                   //la peticion
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(respuesta){
        $("#modal-detalle").modal("show");
        console.log("La respuesta del servidor es: ");
        console.log(respuesta.length);
        console.log("Nombre:",`${nombre}`.trim());

        for(var i=0;i<respuesta.length;i++){

            if (`${respuesta[i].nombreElemento}`.trim()==`${nombre}`.trim()) {
                console.log(nombre);
                $("#tabla-informacion").html(`<tr>
                <th>Nombre Elemento </th>
                <td>${respuesta[i].nombreElemento}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>FechaCreacion</th>
                <td>${respuesta[i].fechaCreacion}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>FechaModificacion</th>
                <td>${respuesta[i].fechaModificacion}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <td>${respuesta[i].usuario}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Tamanio</th>
                <td>${respuesta[i].tamanio}</td>
              </tr> `);
              nombre= '';
            } 

        }

    },
    error:function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

es un ejemplo , lo podes implementar a tu tabla modal y segun sea el formato del archivo que queres editar.

Comment: es necesario usar ajax?

Comment: es una forma de hacerlo, no se si sea necesario

Comment: Hola Javier, me parece que quizá no sea necesario usar una tecnología como ajax para lograr lo que el OP pregunta de acuerdo a la tecnología que usa. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) que te da unas buenas practicas al momento de responder